# PHP email script always emailing plus syntax error?

Tags: php, email

Why doesnt does my contact page email the details from the form regardless of whether you enter a captcha or not. If you end the captcha wrong the error message shows up but the email still sends? Ive been stuck at this for days now.

PHP syntax checker says this block of code has the error:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    $email_to = "myemail@hotmail.co.uk";
    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";


    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
        echo $error."<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['phone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['msg'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');      
    }

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required
    $email = $_POST['email']; // required
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; // not required
    $msg = $_POST['msg']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($msg) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Name: ".clean_string($name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Phone: ".clean_string($phone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Message: ".clean_string($msg)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers); 
?>
```

It says the last line is the problem `?>`

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in CODE on line 65 Errors
>   parsing CODE

Comment: Did you use an IDE wich handle open/close brackets? It can help you to fix this kind of problem by yourself ..

Comment: i used notepad++ but my eyes are hurts :(

Comment: #protip: http://cl.ly/203Q0E0p0D3s341C3u0G

Comment: Aside from the missing `}`, you don't appear to actually be checking the CAPTCHA anywhere...

Answer (score 4):

You are missing the closing `}` for your outer most `if` statement:

```
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {

   // Code

} // This is missing
```

For future reference, `unexpected $end` most likely means you are missing a `}` or a `;` somewhere.

Comment: adding the curley brace stops the page working, i have HTML in this page too: i will show you all my PHP scripts.